# Exceptions in Yesod

Tags: json, haskell, exception, yesod

I had made a daemon that used a very primitive form of `ipc` (telnet and send a String that had certain words in a certain order). I snapped out of it and am now using `JSON` to pass messages to a `Yesod` server. However, there were some things I really liked about my design, and I'm not sure what my choices are now.

Here's what I was doing:

```
buildManager :: Phase -> IO ()
buildManager phase = do
  let buildSeq = findSeq phase
      jid = JobID $ pack "8"
      config = MkConfig $ Just jid
  flip C.catch exceptionHandler $ 
  runReaderT (sequence_ $ buildSeq <*> stages) config
  -- ^^ I would really like to keep the above line of code, or something like it.
  return ()
```

each function in buildSeq looked like this

```
foo :: Stage -> ReaderT Config IO ()

data Config = MkConfig (Either JobID Product) BaseDir JobMap
```

`JobMap` is a `TMVar Map` that tracks information about current jobs.

so now, what I have are Handlers, that all look like this

```
foo :: Handler RepJson
```

`foo` represents a command for my daemon, each handler may have to process a different JSON object.

What I would like to do is send one `JSON` object that represents success, and another JSON object that espresses information about some exception.

I would like `foo`s helper function to be able to return an `Either`, but I'm not sure how I get that, plus the ability to terminate evaluation of my list of actions, `buildSeq`.

Here's the only choice I see

1) make sure `exceptionHandler` is in Handler. Put `JobMap` in the `App` record. Using `getYesod` alter the appropriate value in `JobMap` indicating details about the exception,
which can then be accessed by `foo`

Is there a better way?

What are my other choices?

Edit: For clarity, I will explain the role of`Handler RepJson`. The server needs some way to accept commands such as `build` `stop` `report`. The client needs some way of knowing the results of these commands. I have chosen JSON as the medium with which the server and client communicate with each other. I'm using the Handler type just to manage the JSON in/out and nothing more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Philosophically speaking, in the Haskell/Yesod world you want to pass the values forward, rather than return them backwards. So instead of having the handlers return a value, have them call forwards to the next step in the process, which may be to generate an exception.

Remember that you can bundle any amount of future actions into a single object, so you can pass a continuation object to your handlers and foos that basically tells them, "After you are done, run this blob of code." That way they can be void and return nothing.