# While opening file upload dialogue from website, "Folder not accessible, Access denied" error message comes

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, directory

I am trying to upload files to my website.

Every time when upload dialog opens, it tries to open a default path "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile".

This path is not accessible by every user on all the machines except Admin user.

I even tried to set this default path to "My Documents" but i am not able to get this path runtime.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the My Documents folder, try using Default User's Documents folder instead.

Also check here for more information:
[Exceptions in Yesod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133448/exceptions-in-yesod)